# Quill.js not firing "text-changed" event properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quill

I'm using vue3-quill as a wrapper around quill editor for my vue3 application.

Out of the blue, the component stopped emitting an event when the text content of quill editor changes. Inspecting
[the code of vue3-quill](https://github.com/flyween/vue3-quill/blob/main/src/editor.vue#L134), I noticed the problem is that the inner instance of quill isn't emitting the text-change event.

The event is however emitted correctly when one of the following keys are pressed: enter, space, tab, delete. Other keys don't trigger the event.

I made [this repo](https://github.com/samul-1/test-quill-not-working) to reproduce the error. You can just `npm run serve` it and try and type something in the editor. You'll see the text isn't displayed below, but if you type enter, space, tab, or delete, you'll see the text correctly updated.

I'll add that this started happening today, or at least went unnoticed by my team and me until now. Does this seem to be a bug on Quill's end or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I can confirm that I'm facing the same!